# Get last tree elements, one at a time with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have on one page sections with created events inside div class with `id="tables"`, now I want to load last tree "boxes/elements" from that section in other page `index.php` inside Bootstrap carousel and they need to be loaded one at a time, like a slider is working. I managed with load() method to pull that content, now I don't know how to loop through and get one at the time 
(note: needs to start from end )

My jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
  $(".item").load("showEvents.php #tables:last-child");
});
```

At this point I get only last child. 
And this is html/php part that needs to be loaded:

```
  <div class="main-sections">
                 <?php if(!empty($polls)): ?>
                        <?php foreach($polls as $poll): ?>

                        <div id="tables" class="col-md-3">
                             <h1><?php echo $poll->title; ?></h1>
                            <div class="image"> 
                                <img src="upload/<?php echo $poll->photo; ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div><p><?php echo $poll->pob; ?></p></div>
                            <div><p><?php echo $poll->address ?></p></div>
                            <a href="show_Event.php?rowid=<?php echo $poll->id; ?>" onclick="basicPopup(this.href);return false" ;><button>READ MORE</button></a>
                        </div>

                     <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                <p>Sorry, no poll available right now</p>
                <?php endif; ?>
           </div>
```

Bootstrap Carusel is this one :

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <!-- Indicators -->
                                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                                    </ol>

                                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                        <div class="item active">

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="item">

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="item">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                                   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                      </a>
                                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    </a>

                                </div>
```

Comment: Please add more html using the snippet editor or jsfiddle.net

Comment: I added more info., would be great if you can help me :) Thank you

Comment: First of all, ID must be unique. So change id-"tables" to class="item" and load .main-sections .tables - into carousel-inner and reset the carousel